# convert a dictionary containing array to a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a list of values like below

```
[asset_min,hpc_max,off_median]
```

and a table like this

| item_name | item_value | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hpc_max | 0.25 | 2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000 |
| asset_min | 0.34 | 2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000 |
| off_median | 0.30 | 2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000 |
| hpc_max | 0.54 | 2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000 |
| asset_min | 0.32 | 2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000 |
| off_median | 0.67 | 2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000 |
| asset_min | 0.54 | 2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000 |
| off_median | 0.32 | 2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000 |
| hpc_max | 0.67 | 2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000 |

and I want to group the item_values based on the timestamp in an array type in the order of item names that are in the list

The output I want is

| item_name | item_value | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ["asset_min","hpc_max","off_median"] | [0.34,0.25,0.67] | 2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000 |
| ["asset_min","hpc_max","off_median"] | [0.54,0.54,0.30] | 2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000 |
| ["asset_min","hpc_max","off_median"] | [0.32,0.67,0.32] | 2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000 |

how can I do this using pyspark?

would appreciate any help!

Comment: Please add more details about your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Your DataFrame (df_1)

```
+----------+----------+----------------------------+
|item_name |item_value|timestamp                   |
+----------+----------+----------------------------+
|hpc_max   |0.25      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|
|asset_min |0.34      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|
|off_median|0.3       |2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|
|hpc_max   |0.54      |2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|
|asset_min |0.32      |2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000|
|off_median|0.67      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|
|asset_min |0.54      |2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|
|off_median|0.32      |2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000|
|hpc_max   |0.67      |2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000|
+----------+----------+----------------------------+
```

Import necessary package:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list
```

1. Order the DataFrame by column `timestamp` and `item_name`

```
df_2 = df_1.orderBy("timestamp", "item_name")
```

2. Use the `collect_list` aggregation function to collect the column value based on the column `timestamp`

```
df_2.groupBy("timestamp").agg(
    collect_list("item_name").alias("item_name"),
    collect_list("item_value").alias("item_value")
).show(truncate=False)
```

***Output***

```
+----------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
|timestamp                   |item_name                       |item_value        |
+----------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
|2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000|[asset_min, hpc_max, off_median]|[0.32, 0.67, 0.32]|
|2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|[asset_min, hpc_max, off_median]|[0.54, 0.54, 0.3] |
|2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|[asset_min, hpc_max, off_median]|[0.34, 0.25, 0.67]|
+----------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: I think the item_name must be ordered by the item in the list at the start, not by alphabet

Answer (score -1):

See the below implementation -

**Input dataframe**

```
data = [
    ['hpc_max', 0.25, '2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000'],
    ['asset_min', 0.34, '2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000'],
    ['off_median', 0.30, '2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000'],
    ['hpc_max', 0.54, '2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000'],
    ['asset_min', 0.32, '2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000'],
    ['off_median', 0.67, '2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000'],
    ['asset_min', 0.54, '2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000'],
    ['off_median', 0.32, '2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000'],
    ['hpc_max', 0.67, '2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000']
]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=['item_name', 'item_value', 'timestamp'])

df.show()

+----------+----------+--------------------+
| item_name|item_value|           timestamp|
+----------+----------+--------------------+
|   hpc_max|      0.25|2023-03-01T17:20:...|
| asset_min|      0.34|2023-03-01T17:20:...|
|off_median|       0.3|2023-03-01T17:30:...|
|   hpc_max|      0.54|2023-03-01T17:30:...|
| asset_min|      0.32|2023-03-01T17:35:...|
|off_median|      0.67|2023-03-01T17:20:...|
| asset_min|      0.54|2023-03-01T17:30:...|
|off_median|      0.32|2023-03-01T17:35:...|
|   hpc_max|      0.67|2023-03-01T17:35:...|
+----------+----------+--------------------+
```

**Implementation**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, array_position, col

# define the list of items in the desired order
item_list = ["asset_min", "hpc_max", "off_median"]

# sort the values in ascending as per timestamp and item_name
df1 = df.orderBy(col("timestamp"),col("item_name"))

# group the items by timestamp and collect the item values into an array
result = (df1
    .groupBy("timestamp")
    .agg(collect_list("item_value").alias("item_values"), collect_list("item_name").alias("item_names"))
)

# re-order the item_values array based on the item_list order
result = result.withColumn("asset_min", col("item_values")[array_position(col("item_names"), 'asset_min') - 1]) \
    .withColumn("hpc_max", col("item_values")[array_position(col("item_names"), 'hpc_max') - 1]) \
    .withColumn("off_median", col("item_values")[array_position(col("item_names"), 'off_median') - 1]) \
    .select([col("item_names"), col("item_values"), col("timestamp")])

# show the result
result.show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------------+------------------+----------------------------+
|item_names                      |item_values       |timestamp                   |
+--------------------------------+------------------+----------------------------+
|[hpc_max, asset_min, off_median]|[0.25, 0.34, 0.67]|2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|
|[off_median, hpc_max, asset_min]|[0.3, 0.54, 0.54] |2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|
|[asset_min, off_median, hpc_max]|[0.32, 0.32, 0.67]|2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000|
+--------------------------------+------------------+----------------------------+
```

The code first groups the input DataFrame by the `timestamp` column and collects the `item_value` and `item_name` columns into arrays using the `collect_list()` function.

The arrays are then rearranged according to the desired order of `item_name` values, which is stored in the `item_list` variable.

This is done by using a list comprehension that maps the values in the `item_values` array to the corresponding position of the `item_name` value in the `item_list`.

Comment: it doesn't work as expected..

Comment: Could you elaborate what output are you expecting?